# Itext 7 HtmlConverter can not wrap words that do not contain white space characters

Tags: itext7

I am using `iText html2PDF` version 2.0.0 to convert HTML to PDF.

In my HTML file there are too many words that can not be wrapped in table columns.

It could be done in `iText 5` libraries.
Here are my HTML and java files.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>TM_Report</title>

<style type="text/css">
.div-half-width {
 display: inline;
 width: 50%;
 color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <table width="70%" style="">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td width="50%"><p style="width: 80%; background-color: fuchsia;">3aaaa22aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1</p></td>
    <td width="50%"><p style="width: 80%; background-color: cyan;">4aaaaaa33aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2</p></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 
 <p style="word-break: break-all; width: 80%; background-color: fuchsia;">aaaa22aaaaaa-aaaaaaaaaabb-bbbbbbbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbbaaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaaa-aaaaa1aaaa22-aaaaaaaaaaaa-aaaabbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbb_bbbbbbbaa_aaaaaaaaaaa_aaaaaaaaa1aaaa22_aaaaaaaaaaa_aaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaa_aaaaaaaaaaaaa1</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**CreateAccessiblePDF.java**

```
public class Test {

public static final String sourceFolder = "res/pdfHTML/AccessiblePDF/";
public static final String destinationFolder = "target/output/pdfHTML/AccessiblePDF/";
public static final String[] files = { "Accessibility" };

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    for (String name : files) {
        String htmlSource = sourceFolder + name + ".html";
        String resourceFolder = sourceFolder;
        String pdfDest = destinationFolder + name + ".pdf";
        File file = new File(pdfDest);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new CreateAccessiblePDF().createPdf(htmlSource, pdfDest, resourceFolder);
    }
}

public void createPdf(String src, String dest, String resources) throws IOException {
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
        writerProperties.addXmpMetadata();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputStream, writerProperties);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(src), pdfDoc, props);
        pdfDoc.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I have even tried style sheet "table-layout: fixed;" in table and "word-break: break-all;" in columns but although it is not working in Itext 7 "html2pdf.HtmlConverter" class.

Is there any way to wrap the words which contains no space ( only characters )?

Answer (score 5):

There is.

You need to have a look at the interface

```
public interface ISplitCharacters {

/**
 * Returns <CODE>true</CODE> if the character can split a line. The splitting implementation
 * is free to look ahead or look behind characters to make a decision.
 * @param glyphPos the position of {@link Glyph} in the {@link GlyphLine}
 * @param text an array of unicode char codes which represent current text
 */
boolean isSplitCharacter(GlyphLine text, int glyphPos);

}
```

The default implementation (used by Document) is `DefaultSplitCharacters` which is set to split at various variants of whitespace.

The best solution is to write a class that inherits from `DefaultSplitCharacters` and adds its own extra split characters (like alphanumeric characters).

In order to set it, you can use `setProperty` on RootElement (from which `Document` inherits). The property name is `Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS`

Since you never create a layout `Document` in your original code, that is going to require some tinkering.

You could render to `List<IElement>` with following code:

```
List<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(stream, converterProperties);
```

You can then add the elements to a `Document`, which is pre-set with the correct implementation of `ISplitCharacters`

Comment: Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
            document.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, new DefaultSplitCharacters() {
                @Override
                public boolean isSplitCharacter(GlyphLine text, int glyphPos) {
                    return true;
                }
            });   This one worked